# Import an externally hosted txt file (on github) as PHP code

Tags: php, arrays, github

I have a txt file on github that I'd like to bring into my PHP code.

The txt file is an array of arrays, written in proper PHP syntax.
Example:

```
<?php
$data = [];
$data[101] = [
  "key1" => "value1",
  "key2" => "value2"
];
$data[102] = [
"key1" => "value1",
  "key2" => "value2"
];
?>
```

I've tried a few different methods, including file_get_contents(), file(), and fopen/fread/fclose. Each time it results in my array being broken down into even more arrays. It seems as though I am successfully pulling from github into my code, but the result is really difficult to manage.

So, my question is: is it possible to import an externally hosted text file as PHP code without breaking it down into arrays or converting into strings?

Maybe there is a better method to solving this problem, but I believe this can be accomplished. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Each time it results in my array being broken down into even more arrays." What exactly is happening to the arrays? Can you be more detailed?

Comment: `file_put_contents("downloaded.php", file_get_contents("path/to/remote/file")); include "downloaded.php";` and hope the repo host doesn't figure you're doing this and load their source code with a bit that emails them your db credentials

Comment: Sure @marekful Using the example above, my results might look something like:

Array (
[0]$data = [];,[1]$data[101]=[,[2]"key1",[3]"value1"
);
and so on.
My issue is that I already have arrays and sub arrays declared, and these methods seems to break up what I've written.

Comment: @apokryfos thanks. I'll try that. The repo is mine, shared with contributors. UPDATE I tried your suggestion and the result was a string.

Comment: Whith `include` or `require`, the file content must start with PHP open tag (<?php) for the content to be interpreted as PHP and the array initialised. That should work on remote files if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled.

Comment: You should probably consider having the entire project in Github so this file is part of your commit process then.

Comment: @marekful it's wrapped in a php block. I'll update the question to reflect that